# A (really) fixed DIV in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

In my webpage, I have a header DIV, whose position is set to **fixed**. This means it should remain in the same position on page scrolling, shouldn't it?

On the bottom part of the same webpage, there is a footer DIV, which contains an input text. The position is set to **fixed** for it too. That should go without any problems, but unfortunately the fixed property seems not to work at all.

On my iPhone, when I click on the input field, the keyboard obviously comes up, scrolling the page... The same behaviour on Windows Phone's Internet Explorer. I've not tested it in any Android devices so far, but I'm sure it won't work.

So my question is: how do I make a *really* fixed position DIV? When the keyboard is opened, I want my header DIV to remain in the top of my screen.

Thanks!

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #D3D3D3;text-align:center;background-color:#ff9e42;position: fixed;width:100%;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;">
   <p>This is my DIV content</p>
</div>
<div id="Body" style="padding-top:50px;">
   <iframe src="..." />
</div>
<div id="FOOTER" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;background:#EFEFEF;color:gray;width:100%;border-top:1px solid #D3D3D3;">
   <p>Footer</p>
   <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have written for this.

Comment: The problem is that the keyboard will not change the size of your page, but only overlay over the bottom half. You webpage does not know if there is something everlayed or not.

Comment: You probably forgot to set the top and left properties.

Comment: Hunter Turner, I've updated my question. I've cut off some parts of my header code because they were too long and not relevant.

Comment: You do realize that the viewport changes size when you open a keyboard on mobile, right?  It would be similar to if you were to take your browser and resized it by dragging the bottom edge up.

Comment: Device viewport size change is handled by this tag `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />`

Comment: @PWhite yes, that is how the browser handles the viewport, but that doesn't change the fact that opening a keyboard reduces the available height of a page.  It'll still affect the bottom edge for fixed elements if you change the height of the browser (presumably by opening the keyboard)

Comment: Then, is it possible to keep the DIV on the top? I think this is quite easy to achieve, but I'm missing something and I really can't figure it out...

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861385/fixed-persistent-header-and-scroll-to-focussed-input-fields

Comment: @GermanoPlebani I tried the method you suggested with no success: the header goes off-view without device-size in the viewport tag too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 header {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0; // add this to set proper positioning
     left: 0; // add this to set proper positioning
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  I too assume it's an issue with OP using `bottom` instead of `top`.  When the keyboard opens on mobile devices, the bottom of the viewport is raised.  top however would remain the same. However, I would mention in your answer that OP should remove the `bottom` style or change it to `bottom: auto`.

Comment: @PWhite can you provide a screenshot of the problem?  It might make things clearer.  Also, did you remove the `bottom:0px` before trying dreamypixy's answer?

Comment: Removing the `bottom:0px;` brings the footer in the middle of the page.

Comment: @JosephMarikle writing `bottom:auto;` is like removing the `bottom:0px;`. The footer is placed where the Body DIV ends.

Comment: @PWhite I understand that.  The fact is, you can't have a `bottom:0px` fixed element on mobile and expect the expanding keyboard to not push it up.  The only way to ensure that it doesn't would be to affix it to the top.  I know that completely defeats the purpose of it being a "footer", but ultimately what you are trying to achieve can only be done with a top fixed element.  `bottom: 0` by nature will always keep your footer at the bottom of the viewport, and opening the keyboard by nature will always change the viewport height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100693/discussion-between-pwhite-and-joseph-marikle).